# Calculations on individual digits in a string

Tags: r, string, loops, for-loop

I have a string of concatenated integers:

```
A = "883745"
```

I wish to perform calculations on the individual digits. Here I extract each single number:

```
N1 = as.numeric(substr(A , 1, 1))
N2 = as.numeric(substr(A , 2, 2))
N3 = as.numeric(substr(A , 3, 3))
N4 = as.numeric(substr(A , 4, 4))
N5 = as.numeric(substr(A , 5, 5))
N6 = as.numeric(substr(A , 6, 6))
```

Then I need to calculate:

```
N1 *  nchar(A)    + 
N2 * (nchar(A) - 1) + 
N3 * (nchar(A) - 2) + 
N4 * (nchar(A) - 3) + 
N5 * (nchar(A) - 4) + 
N6 * (nchar(A) - 5)
```

How do I do this in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given a string:

`A <- "883745"`

You can break down your calculation as follows:

```
ans = 0
ans += as.numeric(substr(A , 1, 1)) * (nchar(A) - 0)
ans += as.numeric(substr(A , 2, 2)) * (nchar(A) - 1)
ans += as.numeric(substr(A , 3, 3)) * (nchar(A) - 2)
ans += as.numeric(substr(A , 4, 4)) * (nchar(A) - 3)
ans += as.numeric(substr(A , 5, 5)) * (nchar(A) - 4)
ans += as.numeric(substr(A , 6, 6)) * (nchar(A) - 5)
```

This can be summarized as:

```
ans = 0
for i = 1, 2, ..., 6
  ans += as.numeric(substr(A , i, i)) * (nchar(A) - i + 1)
end for
```

Here, `i` goes from 1 to 6, which is `nchar(A)`, so you are to process all digits in "A".

**Freshman**

Loop as it is.

```
ans <- 0
for (i in 1:nchar(A)) {
  ans <- ans + as.numeric(substr(A , i, i)) * (nchar(A) - i + 1)
}
ans
#[1] 134
```

**Sophomore**

Pre-compute the result of `substring` and `nchar`, then index them in the loop.

```
nc <- nchar(A)
N <- as.numeric(substring(A, 1:nc, 1:nc))
L <- nc:1
ans <- 0
for (i in 1:nc) {
  ans <- ans + N[i] * L[i]
}
ans
#[1] 134
```

**Junior**

Replace the loop by `sum`.

```
nc <- nchar(A)
N <- as.numeric(substring(A, 1:nc, 1:nc))
L <- nc:1
ans <- sum(N * L)
ans
#[1] 134
```

**Senior**

Replace `as.numeric` + `substring` by `utf8ToInt` (@[ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12158757)). Replace `sum` by `crossprod`.

```
N <- utf8ToInt(A) - 48
L <- nchar(A):1
ans <- c(crossprod(N, L))
ans
#[1] 134
```

We can also pack it into one line:

```
c(crossprod(utf8ToInt(A) - 48, nchar(A):1))
#[1] 134
```

Answer (score 3):

`substring` not `substr` is useful for these kind of vectorised substringing operations:

```
nc <- seq(nchar(A))
sum(as.numeric(substring(A, nc, nc)) * rev(nc))
#[1] 134
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be considerably simpler and no loop is necessary. This may be what you are trying to accomplish:

```
A <- 883745
len <- nchar(A)
N <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(A), "")))
N
# [1] 8 8 3 7 4 5
N * (len - 0:5)
# [1] 48 40 12 21  8  5
sum(N * (len - 0:5))
# [1] 134
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this using `utf8ToInt`

```
> sum((utf8ToInt(A) - 48) * nchar(A):1)
[1] 134
```

---

## Benchmark

For those who may care about the speed

```
set.seed(1)
A <- paste0(sample(1e4), collapse = "")

thelatemail <- function() {
  nc <- seq(nchar(A))
  sum(as.numeric(substring(A, nc, nc)) * rev(nc))
}

ZheyuanLi <- function() {
  N <- utf8ToInt(A) - 48
  L <- nchar(A):1
  c(crossprod(N, L))
}

dcarlson <- function() {
  len <- nchar(A)
  N <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(A), "")))
  N * (len - 0:(len - 1))
  sum(N * (len - 0:(len - 1)))
}

TIC <- function() sum((utf8ToInt(A) - 48) * nchar(A):1)


microbenchmark(
  thelatemail(),
  ZheyuanLi(),
  dcarlson(),
  TIC(),
  check = "equivalent"
)
```

we can see

```
Unit: microseconds
          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
 thelatemail() 14615.1 14826.35 15297.588 14945.60 15218.65 24667.8   100
   ZheyuanLi()   856.1   937.30  1856.775   977.50  1017.15 69490.1   100
    dcarlson() 13328.3 14128.95 14815.929 14244.85 14575.45 22232.8   100
         TIC()   755.2   821.75   989.245   854.70   895.10  8863.7   100
```